# Sign in via Google plus or Google

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-plus

Google provides 2 types of sign Oauth. One for google plus and another for google (gmail?)

Before choosing one for my web app. I have some question about this.

Can an user use Google plus sign in to sign-in without google plus account activate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Google+ Sign-in, the user will need to have upgraded their Google account to include Google+.  If the user tries to sign in, has a Google account, and hasn't upgraded, the sign-in button will upgrade them before they land on your site.

Comment: So the upgrade is done by automatic or it actually link to an "asking page" ?

Answer (score 6):

To clarify, if a Google user who has not upgraded to a Google+ account clicks on the Sign in with Google+ button, the same consent dialog that opens will take the user into an account upgrade flow.  This flow is incredibly simple and fast, and returns the user to the consent dialog so that they can continue logging into your app when they finish the upgrade.  If you would like to see this flow, you can "downgrade" one of your demo accounts and then click the button to see what the upgrade flow is like.  Please note that downgrading deletes all of the Google+ data, so be sure you test it on a demo account.

Comment: This is not the case anymore.  See @jkdev's answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the past, you needed Google Plus to sign in.

Now you don't.

Here's [Google's official announcement](http://googleplusplatform.blogspot.com/2013/12/google-sign-in-improvements11.html) (December 11, 2013).

> Google+ Sign-In now supports all Google account types, including Google Apps users, and users without a Google+ profile.

You can check out [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25813938/3345375) and [Google's OpenID Connect page](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenIDConnect) as well.