# Is sign in with Google being replaced with sign in with Google+?

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth

I've been asked to implement sign in with Google so that users with Gmail accounts have an easier time signing in.  In my research I found this [time table](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#timetable) that suggests that it's a better idea to implement sign in with **Google Plus**.  Does that mean that

1) sign in with Google(with out having a google plus account) is going away?

2) users that do not have a Google plus account are forced to sign up to use new sign in with Google auth system?

"If your app authenticates users by any means other than the Google+ Sign-In button, we recommend you switch your app to Google+ Sign-In"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Google+ icon is a bit misleading, but I believe you do not need to have a Google+ profile for login.

According to this [article](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login), "Google+ Sign-In works for all users with a Google account, whether or not they have upgraded to Google+".

So this should answer your questions that sign in with Google without having a + account is not going away.  Additionally, user will not be forced to sign up using the new sign in.

I added the google-plus tag to your question for more visibility.

Hope this helps!